# Debugging Play with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, playframework, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug my Play application with Eclipse. First I launch it using `Run As: Application.launch`

That seems to work.

Then I try to connect the debugger using `Debug As: Connect JPDA to Application.launch`

and I get the error message:

```
"Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect"
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I find that I have to be in the Debug perspective. No idea why. Something to do with the JPDA?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in another answer, the error you are getting is exactly the same one that you get when you attempt to connect the debugger for a second time when it is actually already connected.

That being said, if it doesn't seem to explain your case, look for this line when you initially start the application via `Run As --> Application.launch`:

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000

It tells you on which port it is listening for possible JPDA connections, and if this line is missing then something is wrong. You can modify the `Application.launch` configuration manually (look at the `address` part of `-Xrunjdwp` parameter passed to Java virtual machine) and change the port if necessary. If you make changes you also need to update the `Connect JPDA to Application.launch` run configuration.

Anyways, that is my suggestion - check that the application is indeed listening for possible debugger connections, and try changing the port that is being used for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your application mode is set to dev in your conf/application.conf:
application.mode=dev

Start your application and you should see the following:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000

Right click on the "Connect JPDA.." launcher and Debug As "Connect JPDA..."

Answer (score 0):

I have recieved this error in the past when i have forgotten that the debugger was already connected. Perhaps it is being launched in another way? Also is it possible that debugging is disabled in the app.conf? Just a few things I would check on.

I always run from the command line and debug from Eclipse, might be worth a tray as well. Also try running in test mode if you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown everything and run it again.  What happens is that when you execute the debug it does not show you anything and you might think nothing happens.  You get this error because you might tried several times and you don't know it is already running.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you have to start play from console not run as. Then start debugger run as.

Comment: Not true. You should run the Play app via Eclipse run as. Then connect the debugger via JDPA.

Comment: I'm always using like I said.

Comment: Let's say it otherwise, you can also use the Eclipse Launcher! ;)